# How to display list of mapped array onClick - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component in which I am trying to add pagination functionality. I have made good progress in the structure so far. I have category buttons, where when a category button is selected, the element below shows a list of posts within that category.

For the pagination functionality, I using the WordPress REST API to pull in 5 posts at a time for each category. I am trying to create a "load more" button after the 5th post, where onClick it will load the next 5 posts:

```
const Posts = ({ state, actions }) => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = useState();
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(state.source.api + "/wp/v2/categories")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setCategories(data);
      })
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (categoryId) {
      fetch(state.source.api + "/wp/v2/posts?categories=" + categoryId + "&per_page=5")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setPosts(data);
        });
    }
  }, [categoryId]);

  const [morePosts, setMorePosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (categoryId) {
      fetch(state.source.api + "/wp/v2/posts?categories=" + categoryId + "&per_page=5&page=" + 2)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setMorePosts(data);
        });
    }
  }, [categoryId]);

  return (
    <>
      {categories.length > 0 ? (
        categories.map((category, i) => {
          return (
            <button key={i} onClick={() => setCategoryId(category.id)}>{category.name}</button>
          )
        })
      ) : (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        )
      }

      <div>
        {posts.length === 0 ? (
          <p>No posts...</p>
        ) : (
          <>
            <ol>
              {posts.map((post, i) => {
              return (
                <li key={i}>{post.title.rendered}</li>
              )
            })}
            </ol>
            <button onClick={() => setMorePosts(category.id)}>Load More</button>
              {console.log(morePosts.map((post) => post.title.rendered))}
            </>
          )}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

As you can see, under the last `button` I am consoling the array, and it does return the next 5 posts for the selected category. I am stuck on how to turn that array from the console into actually being shown on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:

Load more button changes the page number.
When page number is changed: useEffect fires and posts are refetched/rerendered based on page number param.

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!categoryId) {
        return;
    }

    let url = `${state.source.api}/wp/v2/postscategories=${categoryId}&per_page=5"`;

    if (page > 1) {
        url += `&page=${page}`;
    }

    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setPosts([...posts, ...data]);
        });
  }, [categoryId, page]);

  <button onClick={() => { setPage(page + 1); }}>Load more</button>
```

Comment: That does work, thank you! The way this loads, it overwrites the first five posts with the next five posts. Do you know how I would be able to concatenate the "next" posts at the end of the first posts?